# Nested class not applied in LESS "function"

Tags: html, css, less

Consider this LESS file...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .container(100px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px){
    .container(40px);
}

.container(@size){
    margin: 50px;

    div.left{
        background-color: blue;
        font-size: @size;
    }

    div.right{
        background-color: red;
        font-size: @size;
    }
}
```

And this HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the right `<div>` working perfectly fine, but the left one has no style applied to it... what's wrong here?

Note: I tried > operator, & operator, erasing the **div** and having **.left** nothing worked...

Comment: I'm not seeing what your function does. Arguments are usually applied to properties, not selectors. http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-functions

Comment: Your code does not create `.container div.left` and `.container div.right` selectors as you probably think it to. Note that a mixin call expands mixin *contents* not "contents *and* the mixin name" (hence you code above creates just `div.left` and `div.right`. For the proper example see @Josh answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running a mixin without a proper selector block.

Try changing your code to this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
  .container {
    .container(100px);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px){
  .container {
    .container(40px);
  }
}

.container(@size){
    margin: 50px;

    div.left{
        background-color: blue;
        font-size: @size;
    }

    div.right{
        background-color: red;
        font-size: @size;
    }
}
```

## [Working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNOyYN)

Comment: It does.  I'll edit the example into the answer, but ensure that your media query is doing what you expect it to.  Try adding a "default" path outside of a media query.

Comment: @Muli see [demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/rVeaOM?editors=110). So if it's not working for you double-check your HTML.

Comment: Sure.  Need to make sure your media queries are doing what you're expecting them to do. The two you had likely weren't what you'd expect, one would only apply if the viewport was under 1200px, the other only if the viewport was under 200px (very unlikely).  Since there was no specificity difference, likely you'd only see the under 1200px one.  Second, you need to use parameterized mixins (functions) as a property, not as a selector itself.  So instead of `.container(100px)` you'd do `.my-element-container{.container-properties(100px;}`.  Make sense?

Comment: Plus, use a default path when you can.  You never know what a client's going to be viewing your site on, so having one that serves everything not covered by your media queries is always a good idea.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to resize fonts, is this a good solution? (I don't need intermediate values...)